# Не могу создать индекс на вьюхе. Use an explicit CONVERT with a deterministic style value

Tags: sql-server, view, index

SQL Server 2012 Standart
Создаю вьюху:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[testindex]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
D.ID,
D.CustomerID,
C.Client_name,
P.Sku_Code,
P.Sku_Name,
C.cChain,
D.DLC,
convert(datetime,D.theDate) as theDate,
D.Stock
FROM SaleOUT.Destination as D
INNER JOIN dbo.Clients as C
ON C.Client_code = D.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Products as P
ON D.ProductID = P.SKU_Code
Where DLC <> '19000101'

GO


create unique clustered index indexOne on dbo.testindex
(id)
go
```

Пишет следующую ошибку:

> Msg 10139, Level 16, State 1, Line 35 Cannot create index on view
>   'Planning.dbo.FreshnessOldness' because the view uses an implicit
>   conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime. Use an explicit
>   CONVERT with a deterministic style value.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source
>   or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is
>   specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a
>   constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are
>   nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. **Styles greater than
>   100 are deterministic**, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.

укажите стиль преобразования даты для CONVERT

Answer (score 3):

Определение индексированного представления должно быть детерминированным. Представление детерминировано, если детерминированы все выражения в списке выбора, а также в предложениях WHERE и GROUP BY. Детерминированные выражения возвращают одни и те же результаты при каждом вычислении с одним и тем же набором входных значений. Только детерминированные функции могут использоваться в детерминированных выражениях. Например, функция DATEADD детерминирована, т. к. всегда возвращает один и тот же результат для любого заданного набора значений аргументов трех ее параметров. Функция GETDATE не детерминирована, т. к. всегда вызывается с одним и тем же аргументом, но каждый раз возвращает разные значения. (с)

[ОТСЮДА](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions)

Попробуйте заменить строку

```
convert(datetime,D.theDate) as theDate,
```

на строку

```
convert(datetime,D.theDate, 103) as theDate, 
/* 103 должно быть заменено на тот формат в котором у вас хранятся данные */.
```

должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, помогло.
И натолкнуло еще на дополнительные изменения
нужно еще  добавить такое изменение:

```
Where DLC <> convert(datetime,'19000101', 103)
```

И еще такой вопрос. 
Сработает создание индекса если добавить в запрос такие условия:

```
datepart (month, D.theDate) AS D_Month,
DatePart (year, D.theDate) AS D_Year,
DatePart (WEEK, D.theDate) AS D_Week,
DatePart (WEEKDAY, D.theDate) AS D_DayOfWeek
```

Comment: если v.theDate это dateeime то должно сработать. Исходите из того, возможно ли изменение результа работы данной функции, при изменении например настроек среды, страны доступа и тд.

Comment: Функция Datepart является не детерминиованной.
Сервер не пропускает ее.
Поэтому планирую создать вьюху на основе этой и там уже использовать эту функцию.

Comment: упс, да не гляну в справку, но общий принцип я надеюсь вы поняли